# Excel to CSV Java library

Tags: library, java, document-converter, microsoft-excel, csv

I am looking for a Java library (preferably in Maven Central) that can read XLS and XLSX and save the sheet to CSV.

I am looking for something higher level than poi and jxl as neither of these have direct export to CSV without writing lots of code.

I am also aware of the poi xls2csv sample but I am looking for a reusable library and not a class to paste in my project.

Comment: Please give some feedback.

Comment: There will always be some customization, configuration or _writing code_. Since CSV is used with different **delimiters**, **quotes**, **charsets**, **formats** for number/date/time. Thus popular available libraries won't have that __one-size-fits-all__ method called `DirectExporter.fromXlsToCsv( xlsFile, csvFile )`.

Comment: Can you reveal some context for your need. Why you don't want to write code? For which (recurring) tasks will it be used? How should your desired _higher level_ look like (maybe in pseudo-code)? What is the environment you want to integrate the library?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is a 2.5 year old question. Excel can open a file and can also export to CSV with sensible-ish defaults. So `DirectExporter.fromXlsToCsv( xlsFile, csvFile )` is what I was looking for back then. I believe I had a generic CSV comparison library and exporting XLS(X)  to CSV would have made it a (reasonably) useful generic XLS(X) comparison. Since it was supposed to be generic, having POJOs for each file is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

[Spire.XLS for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/xls-for-java.html) library is capable of reading XLS/XLSX files and saving them as CSV. You just need to write 4 lines of code.

Maven dependencies:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.e-iceblue</id>
        <name>e-iceblue</name>
        <url>https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>e-iceblue</groupId>
        <artifactId>spire.xls</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Save a worksheet of an XLS/XLSX file as CSV:

```
import com.spire.xls.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class ExcelToCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a workbook
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();    
        //Load an xlsx or xls file
        workbook.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Test1\\Desktop\\sample.xlsx");    
        //Get the first sheet
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);    
        //Save the sheet as CSV
        sheet.saveToFile("output/ToCSV_out.csv", ",", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

For more information, you can read the documentation here: [Java: Convert Excel to CSV and Vice Versa](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.XLS-for-Java/Program-Guide/Conversion/Java-Convert-Excel-to-CSV-and-Vice-Versa.html)

Comment: It looks useful and what I was looking for at the time of the question. It should be pointed out for future readers that it is a 30-day trial and not an open-source library.

Answer (score 0):

Searching GitHub I found **[Coreoz/Windmill](https://github.com/Coreoz/Windmill)**:

> Windmill is a **library** to parse or write Excel and CSV files through a **fluent API** that takes advantage of **Java 8 Stream and Lambda** features.
>
> Windmill targets the writing/parsing of List/Collection data. It will especially stand out for use cases like exporting/importing a result set from/to a database.
>
> It is based on the projects **Apache POI** and **OpenCSV** to manipulate Excel and CSV files.

Plus it's available in **[Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.coreoz/windmill/1.2.0/jar)**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.coreoz</groupId>
  <artifactId>windmill</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is a slight improvement over just using POI and OpenCSV directly. It appears that it still requires a fair amount of code to be written though. However, now that code is inline in the fluent API.

Comment: In my experience with _XLS(X)-to-CSV_ it seems currently the best free java-lib for your requirements. The 5-10 lines of code are needed to integrate the lib in your code-base as well as configurate your custom conversion-mapping (CSV-delimiters, formatting, and so on).